# Question about temperature limit to infinity

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics, quantum-statistics

I want to find the limit of T to infinity for a specific function:

$$\frac{a^{2}L^2}{4kT^2}\frac{e^{aL/2kT}}{(e^{aL/2kT}-1)^2}$$

When T approaches infinity, the e on the top becomes 1. Furthermore I think, when taking the limit of T to infinity for $e^{1/T} -1$, it equals 1/T. So my final answer would be $\frac{a^{2}L^2}{4k}$.

Is this correct? Or do the coefficients dissapear to because of the $T^2$ making the coefficients negligible resulting in a final answer 1? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, should it be $4k^2T^2$ in the denominator of the leading fraction?

Comment: @MarkH You mean in the first equation I gave? I had to multiply the equation by the partial derivative of beta over T, so it should be 1/$kT^2$ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify, let's assign $x = aL/2kT$.
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{a^{2}L^2}{4kT^2}\frac{e^{aL/2kT}}{(e^{aL/2kT}-1)^2} =\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{kx^2e^x}{(e^{x}-1)^2}$$
This is a $0/0$ form, so we can use L'Hopital's rule.
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{kx^2e^x}{(e^{x}-1)^2} = k\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2xe^x + x^2e^x}{2(e^x - 1)e^x} = k\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2x + x^2}{2(e^x - 1)} = k\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2 + 2x}{2e^x} = k$$